# textDidEndEditing: Objective c example

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstextfield

So I know you have to put this in the .h file:

```
- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

BUT what do I call in the .m file?? How do I show that text is done editing in one of several NSTextFields?

I looked around on the internet, but it seems pretty vague on how to use it correctly.

Any ideas?
Elijah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `UITextFieldDelegate`. It will give you the method callbacks you want, such as `textfieldDidEndEditing`. It should pass the text field which you can then identify by object comparison or tag value.

#### UPDATE

Code sample for the delegate callback. Be sure to add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your .h file. Also specific your textField's delegate property, `textField.delegate = self` in your code or in IB.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyDone) {
    // the textfield with the Done return key is what I care about
    self.value2 = [textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
  }
}
```

Comment: Of which part: Delegate or the method?

Comment: See above. Hopefully that get's you started.

Comment: Note that the poster is asking about NSTextField, not UITextField. Not that it necessarily changes the answer much, but Cocoa and Cocoa Touch aren't always identical.